# The attribute 'name' is invalid - XCode Flutter app archiving

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

I've been trying to archive my Flutter app on XCode for App Store Connect, and I keep running into the following error:

[image]

I've gone through `info.plist` and made sure all of my build settings do not contain illegal characters in any of the bundle or product names. For some reason XCode is injecting `XC` into some name field that I can't seem to locate to prevent from happening.

Has anyone encountered this before?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Had the same issue today, for me it was underscores (_) in the bundle identifier which caused the problem. Changing them to hyphens (-) fixed it for me.